# Changing a subrepository url in mercurial, from https to ssh. Any problems doing that?

Tags: mercurial, ssh, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I have in a `.hgsub`, an entry to a subrepository, that is invoked using `https`.

```
myrepo = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project
```

Now, I want to use `ssh` since both repositories are mine and I've created a ssh key. So, it would be:

```
myrepo = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/project
```

I haven't changed, and haven't tested either. Does someone knows if changing this url is going to add some kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine as long as you have a password or public/private key combo to use with ssh as that matches their example syntax here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/QuickStart

However, you can also do the following:

```
ssh://user@website.org//absolute/path/to/repo
```

This is what I have in my .hg/hgrc when I push/pull projects to my home server (user@ can be eliminated if you have the same username on both machines).

Comment: I already have this line in my .hg/hgrc, problem is this repo is referenced in another by myrepo = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project: so, when I do a pull in the parent repository, it tries to pull the subrepo using https. I already have the keys, and they work if I try to connect to the repositories, the problem with https is when I try to pull the parent.